# how to store parsed xml file to a sqlite database in Android?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, xml-parsing

i am making a project in that i required synchronize data between server mysql data and local sqlite data...
With the help oh php i have created mysql data XML file.... so now i know the parsing of xml data but how can i store it in sqlite(local) database ??

Please help me i ll appreciate your help ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you are parsing xml file you have key-value structure and maybe something else so create database with column named by parameters, for each row insert name of node or its own id and then values which you need, if you need to use only key-value maybe better way it'll be to put it into shared preferences.

Another option, jut save whole xml as a standard string(text) and then you can get it and parse it once again.

Everything depends on that what kind of structure you have.

[HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) information about storing in database

Comment: see i think you did not got my question ...just tell me hot to store XML file data to sqlite in  java (Android)?

Comment: I'm not sure you can save XML FILE try to save content of xml file

Comment: so you need tutorial how to save something in database?

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/   sometimes ask google

Comment: you give me link how to connect sqlite database.,... and use it ... and i asked how to store parsed xml file to a sqlite database in Android ?..

Comment: What i want and wht u give me .. !! ? :( :( :((

Comment: dude steps: first CREATE DATABASE IN ANDROID, next access, than save, to save you have to open database which you CREATED!!! another sources with out looking: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Comment: BTW. developer.android.com Reference-> package: android.database.sqlite class: SQLiteDatabase method: insert